# How to make native (realtime) blur in Sprite-Kit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, real-time, native, blur

I am using this code for my blur, but it doesn't seem to work. Or it kinda works. I can only see a grey coloured background instead of the blurred scene. (First picture, I have captured it using a screenshot, but that captures it like its working great, weird.) And when i swipe down, it blurs the scene normally.

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
[blurEffectView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];
```

[The screenshot captures it normally but i can only see grey background.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rgnI.png)

[Here when i swipe down, it works like charm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtKCz.png)

I have found different solutions for this, but those were only static. I want this type of blur, it doesn't even drop any fps. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

1. The **blur** effect is provided by a Core Image Filter.
2. Every Core Image Filter can be used with a `SKEffectNode`
3. `SKScene` is an `SKEffectNode`

then...

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        super.didMove(to:view)

        self.filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius": 10])
        self.shouldEnableEffects = true

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there is still no blur, i have added your code to my scene. 'CIFilter *blur = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [blur setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:10] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    scene.filter = blur;' Am i missing something?

Comment: @BalázsGyöngyösi: It's my fault, there was a missing instruction         `self.shouldEnableEffects = true`. Now it works. I updated my code in the answer as well.